# Will sound wave travel faster if we are traveling while speaking?

Tags: waves, acoustics

I don't know if this is a stupid question or not, please tell me if it is.

I will use an example to illustrate my doubt.

Suppose I am moving to the right with a speed of $30ms^{-1}$. And sound wave moves at a speed of $343ms^{-1}$. If I am speaking during speaking. What is the speed of the sound wave moving to the right from an observer's view?

I think the answer is still $343ms^{-1}$ , I want to check if it is correct and why is it the case?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The speed of sound is the speed of the excitation propagating through the media, and it is independent on the velocity of source, or the observer. However, there will be a frequency shift, because the observer will now encounter the wave crests more often. It is actually a pronounced *Doppler effect* https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doppler_effect :
$$
\omega = \frac{c \pm v_r}{c \pm v_s} \omega_0
$$
where $v_r$ is a speed of receiver, and $v_s$ - speed of source

Comment: Also, google for what happens if you are moving towards the listener with a speed *greater* than 343 m/s. (Hint: you will reach the listener before they have heard anything you said).